# Mathematical model/open source code to obtain displaced geometries along a normal mode from vibrational frequency calculation

Tags: orca, vibrational-frequency

I am looking for a mathematical model which will produce the displacement vectors from vibrational frequency calculations. I use ORCA for the calculation of the frequencies and generally use Chemcraft to visualize the frequencies. We can generate the displaced coordinates there using the GUI. However, I want to implement it in the automated script which can generate the displaced geometries along different normal modes with a specified displacement. Is there any open-source code available implementing such a model?

Comment: You know that ORCA can do that itself, right? That's how it calculates its VPT2 properties. That being said, I think it might be worth you looking up normal coordinate analysis and Wilson's **GF** matrix method? I don't understand it, personally, but, after a quick skim of *Molecular Vibrations* (Wilson, Decius and Cross), it looks like chapter 4 might discuss it. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and the reference helped me a lot to understand the model. I was looking for any kind of reference to open-source code that can be implemented easily.

Comment: Ah, you might want to add that to your question—currently, it sounds like you are asking for the mathematical theory so you can develop the code yourself; you have not actually asked for a piece of code to do it.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: The open-source python package autodE does this internally for checking transition state validity. Take a look at this function here https://github.com/duartegroup/autodE/blob/1075b84d22e1bcc0ceba69152305ce155aed4494/autode/transition_states/base.py#L414.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't have such a script on-hand, it's really easy to write one using [cclib](https://cclib.github.io/) which helpfully provides [`vibdisps`](https://cclib.github.io/data_notes.html#vibdisps) for vibrational files.

> The attribute vibdisps stores the Cartesian displacement vectors from the output of a vibrational frequency calculation. .. `M x N x 3`, where `M` is the number of normal modes and `N` is the number of atoms. `M` is typically 3N-6 (3N-5 for linear molecules).

You want something like this:

```
import numpy as np

import cclib
from cclib.parser import ccopen

# which mode do you want to displace
mode_number = 1
file = ccopen(filename)
molecule = file.parse()

# the atom labels (here as atomic numbers)
labels = molecule.atomnos

coords = np.asarray(molecule.atomcoords[-1]).reshape(-1,3)
mode = modes[mode_number]
displaced = coords + 2.0*(mode / np.linalg.norm(mode))
# output as XYZ or whatever
```